# How can I type a single quote in Textmate?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macros, textmate

Textmate has automatic quotation closure (clojure) and that's great most of the time. But a lot of times I just need to type a single ' or " and as far as I know there is no way to do this - which is really annoying.

If I type `"` I get `"%"` where % represents the cursor.

If I type `'` I get `'%'`.

Next, I instictively press "delete" to remove the one to the left side of the cursor. Which has an unintended behavior of deleting both quotation marks.

So next I have to type `"` again, followed by right arrow, and then delete. I like most things about TextMate **but this is really freakin' annoying that I end up pressing 5 KEYS to be able to get a single character.**

There has to be a better way to do this! I've tried pressing cmd,option,fn,and shift when typing the character with no luck. HELP!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `"`, and then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

This should forward-delete the second quote, instead of trying to backspace over the first quote.

From the [manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text#auto-paired_characters_quotes_etc):

> If you type an opening character and then delete it using backward delete (⌫) then the auto-inserted character will also be deleted. If you only want to delete the auto-inserted character, use forward delete instead (⌦).

Comment: You mean `Shift`-`Backspace`? (works for me)

Comment: @slhck He's on OS X (Textmate is an OS X application), and based upon the assumption that he's using a Mac, the key labelled "Delete" is the backspace key on windows keyboards, and Shift+Delete performs the same function as the "Delete" key on windows keyboards. See [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/pix/mackeyboard.jpg) image of Mac keyboard.

Comment: Uhm. I've always been on Macs (that's why I said, "works for me", because I have a Mac and TextMate on it...). Haven't seen a keyboard labeled with "delete" yet though. Seems to be a U.S. thing.

Comment: @slhck Ah, never considered if it was a regional thing. The Apple keyboards in the US have their backwards-delete key labelled "Delete" instead of "backspace". Confusing as hell since the forward-delete key is still labelled "Delete ⌦"

Comment: Yep, [German keyboard](http://www.apfelwahn.de/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/alu_keyb_2.jpg) has no backward delete symbol (⌫), but a backspace. The forward delete symbol (⌦) is however labeled "Entf.", which translates to "delete". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: cool. that actually makes sense, although I wish there was still a way to use option or something to just type a single quote.

Comment: `fn` `delete` works for me, I don't know if they changed it.